# How to read a txt file from disk and inline the content using XSTL?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xslt and I need to read a file from disk. The file is a simple text file which I would like to read the full content and inline it in my output html/pdf file. Is this possible?

Comment: It is only the reading of a file which I have no idea if it can be done.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for links to the functions that you may find useful in text processing with XSLT. There are also links to non-trivial examples how I have been using these functions in serious solutions, such as my parser for JSON and my solution of Tim Brey's Wide-Finder problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how it can be done, using XSLT 2.0's `unparsed-text()` function:

```
D:\MiLu\Dev\XML :: more > eins.txt
Ich bin die eins.
^Z

D:\MiLu\Dev\XML :: more > zwei.txt
Ich bin die zwei.
^Z

D:\MiLu\Dev\XML :: saxon unparsed-text.xml unparsed-text.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eins>
   <zwei> bla </zwei>
   <drei>Ich bin die eins.&#xD;
&#xD;
</drei>
   <vier>Ich bin die zwei.&#xD;
&#xD;
</vier>
</eins>

D:\MiLu\Dev\XML :: more /t1 unparsed-text.xml
<eins>
 <zwei> bla </zwei>
 <drei>
  <textfile href="eins.txt"/>
 </drei>
 <vier>
  <textfile href="zwei.txt"/>
 </vier>
</eins>

D:\MiLu\Dev\XML :: more /t1 unparsed-text.xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="textfile[ @href ]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="unparsed-text( @href )"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For XSLT 1.0, you'd need a workaround involving an XML wrapper file referencing the textfile using an external entity, and the `document()` function.

Answer (score 1):

**See [this post from my blog](http://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2007/11/09/wide-finder-in-xslt-deriving-new-requirements-for-efficiency-in-xslt-processors/) showing an example how to parse a huge text (log) file, solving [the Wide-Finder problem](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/09/20/Wide-Finder)**.

Of course, the standard XSLT 2.0 function **[`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#function-unparsed-text)** and **[the XPath 2.0 functions for regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#string.match)** are used.

If more complicated text processing is involved, one can use the XSLT 2.0 instructions for regular-expressions-text-processing: **[`<xsl:analyze-string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-analyze-string)**, **[`<xsl:matching-substring>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-matching-substring)** and **[`<xsl:non-matching-substring>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-non-matching-substring)** as, for example, I do in **[my JSON parser, written entirely in pure XSLT 2.0](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?view=markup&sortby=date)**.

Answer (score -2):

Xslt alone has no mechnanism for doing such activity.  However scripts can be written to run inside xsl.  In .NET this also includes extension objects.  You do not mention what language/environment is performing the transform.

With inline scripts/extension objects you can then use the languages IO class library to open the file and return the string.

- [Extension Objects when
  transforming](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323370)
- [Mxsml inline xslt script blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx)

Comment: It would appear java has similar abilities? http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html